# Why do all the enemies in my scene take damage when I damage just one?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have a script spawning enemies in my scene. Every enemy game object has an enemy script on it that detects a tap or mouse click.

When a click on enemy is detected the health decrements and if it goes below 0 that gameObject is destroyed.

```
void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                if (hit.transform.tag == "Enemy")
                {
                    health--;
                    if (health <= 0)
                        Destroy(gameObject);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when I click on an enemy, every enemy in the scene takes damage rather than just the one I am clicking on.

Can't figure out why this is. As for some reason the `raycast` applies to all the enemies in the scene rather than where I am clicking?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What is `health`? Can you show its declaration? And where is it declared?

Comment: I have no Unity expericence, but you should probably test whether the object that is hit is the current object. `if (hit.collider.gameObject == gameObject) ...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Because you never check *which* enemy

This line: `if (hit.transform.tag == "Enemy")` only checks to see if the ray hit *an* enemy ("oh my god, they shot Bob!"). To check to see if the ray hit *itself* you want `if(hit.transform == this.transform)` instead ("I've been shot!").

Or better yet, don't have this code attached to all your enemies (10000 enemies, 10000 raycasts!) and have *one* script attached to something like the camera that performs the existing check, but replaces `health--;` line with `hit.transform.GetComponent<Enemy>().Damage()` which will deal damage *only* to the enemy the mouse is pointing at.

Comment: Thank you. You're right putting this on camera also solved my problem and also solved the performance issues I was having as enemies in scene increased. :)